# Can I put a 60 amp breaker in my sub panel that also runs ona 60 amp breaker from main panel

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a sub-panel that leads from my main circuit breaker in my house. The breaker in the main box is a 60 amp leading to the sub. Is it okay to run a 60 amp break in the sub panel for an electric car charger?

I only have a couple 20 amp outlets connected to the sub panel and another 40 amp breaker for my welder. Anytime I would be charging the car, I wouldn't be using anything else except maybe one outlet for a radio.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the charger rating? Chargers are considered continuous devices so unless below 45 amps it really takes up the entire calculated load. (Continuous loads are calculated at 125% of there load rating)

Comment: What size are the feeder wires from the main to the subpanel, and what are you using for a car charger?  Also, can you get us photos of the labeling on the insides of the doors of the main panel and the existing subpanel both please?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact 200 going into the house.

Comment: @EdBeal 48 amps continuous, Tesla recommended 60 amp 2-pole

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I believe when I hooked up the sub panel it was 6ga. Tesla wall charger, sure can - https://imgur.com/a/mNgtZ1V https://imgur.com/k1YDvQY

Comment: @Brian -- is that 6AWG wire in the form of NM or UF cable, some other type of cable (SE or armored/metal-clad), or individual wires in conduit?  Also, can you get us photos of the label on the inside left of the subpanel's box and the inside of the main panel's door please?

Comment: Code requires the load calculation to be 125% for continue loads plus 100% of the non continuous loads so the 60 amp feeder is not large enough. Feeders below wire size 1 (100 amps) are required to use the 60 degree table but internet only electricians will provide other advice.

Answer (score 2):

### Depends on your feeder cable

The cable from the main panel to the subpanel is **feeder**.

The cable from the subpanel to the EVSE is a **branch circuit**.

A cable can't be both a feeder *and* a branch circuit. That is to say, the 60A feeder can't simply be tapped and also sent to the EVSE.   It needs to go to the subpanel, and then through a 60A branch circuit breaker.

**Here's the thing.  There's no such thing as a 60A feeder.** Does not exist.   Either

- your wiring is 55A (#6 copper NM-B or UF-B or other #6 copper rated 60C temperature) and since 55A breakers don't exist, you round up to 60A breaker.  Or
- your wiring is 65A (#6Cu or #4Al of a more advanced insulation type) and you downbreakered to 60A for some reason.

The difference is that in one case, you have 55A feeder. In the other case you have 65A feeder.  **You cannot provision more load on the panel than the feeder can provide** which may mean 55A.

With EVSEs, you must provision 125% of the actual ampacity.  So a 48A EVSE needs 60A provisioned to it (which is not the same as a 60A breaker).   You cannot provision 60A from a 55A feeder.

### Room for everything else

We can take for granted that the welder and EVSE won't be in use at the same time; #1 they need to be in the same physical space, and #2 the supply breaker will say "no way Jose".

However, we need to leave room for the two 20A circuits, and that's an imbroglio.  Code does *not* say "just add up all the breaker trips".

First, the NEC 2014 requirement for a 20A circuit isn't a factor, *[because the purpose of that requirement is to power an EVSE](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/nec-2014-garages-receptacles.107615/)* and you are already providing that via separate means.  So that's off the table.

(and even if you had a second EV, Tesla's Wall Connectors [know how to share](https://www.tesla.com/support/load-sharing-tesla-wall-connector), and Tesla uses the same protocol as the standard J1772 connector, so it will still work with a third party EV using an adapter).

The only other guidance NEC gives us *for domiciles* is a square-foot calculation of 3 VA per square foot (or 1 amp per 40 square feet) in NEC 220.12. 220.14(J) tells us not to worry about it for domiciles, since it's folded into the above 220.12 calculation... it says "No additional load calculations shall be required for such outlets".  But that's intended as a catch-all for *service* to the entire domicile, it was never imagined for a garage subpanel.

The last guidance we have is for non-domiciles at 220.14(H) and (I)...  where 180 VA (1.5A) per receptacle is allocated.  A common duplex recep counts as 1.  A long surface conduit power strip counts as 1.  You need to do this for each of the 2 circuits, but since they are on opposite poles, you only need to count the larger.  Not a perfect solution, but Code does not cover this well.

By my math, 3 receptacles = 4.5A + the 60A provisioned to the EVSE = 64.5A.

That's OK on a 65A feeder. Though you might want to address the under-breakering of that feeder e.g. by fitting a 70A breaker.

If it's a 55A feeder, you'll need to set the DIP switches inside the EVSE to advertise itself as a 40A unit ([understand how EVSE ampacity works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)).  That way, the EVSE derates 125% to 50A.  That + e.g. 4.5A for the receps = 54.5 amps and you're in limits.

Comment: It violates code and since I got a down vote I will spread the wealth

Comment: @EdBeal I didn't give you a downvote.  Your answer is credible and you even used the new keyboard with the enter key :)  I don't generally DV unless an answer is house-on-fire wrong - highly improbable coming from you.  Do you WANT me to start downvoting your weak answers?

Comment: @EdBeal Also, you are entirely correct that we can't ignore the recep circuits. My line of thinking is you're not charging an EV and also using 120V tools like table saw and dust collector.  However yeah, chargers lights, etc.  The welder can be ignored, since concurrent use with the EVSE is pretty much out of the question for several reasons.

Comment: My answers may be weak but yours is wrong. By a simple calculation the feeder is undersized.

Comment: @EdBeal I have greatly expanded to explain why I think that.

Answer (score -1):

That would not pass inspection in my state so I would say NO.

See NEC 625.41 the feeder in this case is required to be sized at 125% and the non continuous loads on the same feeder shall not be less than the sum of the non continuous plus 125% of the continuous loads.

This basic statement is throughout the code so it would not pass.

If you could reduce or tap down you may get approval.
My jurisdiction is trying to help people get into electric but this is a common stumbling block for DIY that they will not allow as the feeder is oversubscribed.

Comment: I love the down votes from internet only electricians that can not read the code references.

Comment: You mention "by a simple calculation the feeder is undersized", maybe you could add the simple calculation to the answer.  Note that the 125% thing is already covered, the "60A" charger draws 48A actual.